# ActionScript 3 onMetaData video duration - can't store value

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, actionscript

I have standard NetStream for video connection in AS3:

The Code:

```
public class VideoInit extends MovieClip
{
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;


    public var video:Video;
    public var nc:NetConnection;
    public var ns:NetStream;
    public var meta:Object;
    public var _duration; //  <----- the variable



    public function VideoInit()
    {
        video = new Video(480,270); 
        addChild(video);
        nc = new NetConnection();
        nc.connect(null);
        ns = new NetStream(nc);

        meta = new Object();

        ns.client = meta;
        video.attachNetStream(ns);
        ns.play("video.f4v"); 


        meta = new Object();

        meta.onMetaData = function(meta:Object) // <---- the method
        {
            _duration = meta.duration

        }
        ns.client = meta;
     }
```

Now, everyime that the onMetaData method executes, the variable _duration stores the value, but right after the debugger step leaves the method, _duration value is set back to *unindentified*.
I've tried to do a workaround with Array, by pushing the value, but the same thing happens, the Array resets. What could it be wrong?

**Edit:**

Any object that stores the duration value self destructs as soon as onMetaData is complete. Doesn't really matter how I Implement it.

Comment: Try using a Setter for the duration that only changes it if it is a valid number. Problem I think is that onMetaData is being called but the meta object is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

The code you've posted would not compile and, even if it did, it could cause other problems.

Suggestion: ditch the *meta* Object and instead set *ns.client = this;*

This works:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;

    public class VideoInit extends Sprite
    {
        private var video:Video;
        private var nc:NetConnection;
        private var ns:NetStream;
        private var _duration:Number; //  <----- the variable

        public function VideoInit()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        }

        private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
            video = new Video(480,270); 
            addChild(video);
            nc = new NetConnection();
            nc.connect(null);

            ns = new NetStream(nc);
            ns.client = this;// meta;

            video.attachNetStream(ns);
            ns.play("video.f4v");
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, testTheValueOfDuration);
         }

         public function onMetaData(e:Object):void
         {
            _duration = e.duration
            trace('_duration:', _duration);

            testTheValueOfDuration();
         }

         private function testTheValueOfDuration(e:MouseEvent = null):void
         {
            trace('Seriously, what is the value of _duration?', _duration);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: That Works, but not if you want to access testTheValueOfDuration() from anywhere other than onMetaData function. The same goes for the _duration variable.

Comment: I only threw in testTheValueOfDuration() to show that the code solves the problem you described: the value of _duration no longer equals 'undefined' outside of the onMetaData() method. Instead, the value of  _duration set in onMetaData() will persist and be accessible to other methods in the class until either the instance of VideoInit is destroyed or, for some reason, you were to assign a different value to it. If you want to make _duration accessible outside of the class, you would only need to create a public getter.

Comment: Well, yes. In theory it should be like that. But it isn't. onMetaData makes two calls to the setter, but as soon as function complete, var _duration is empty again.

Comment: I've made three small changes to the code I posted two days ago: _duration is now typed to Number. Shouldn't be necessary, but there's no reason not to. Second, I added a stage mouse mouse down event listener which calls testTheValueOfDuation(). Third, I modified the method signature of testThatValueOfDuration to include an optional MouseEvent. Every time I click on the stage, I see a trace message showing the correct duration of the video. Try it out and let me know if you see the same thing.

Comment: Yes, In that case I do get a correct value. But I can't be click dependent to get the value.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "click dependent"? Once the _duration property is set in onMetaData, you can do whatever you want with it, no mouse clicks required. Do you need the class to dispatch a custom event containing _duration's value?